# PHP/Jquery Save data doesnt show on mysql [longblob]

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can anyone help me solve this problems? I am trying to insert data in my MySQL but i seems to fail each time. when I'm using the same code for just text data, its works just fine, now i am trying to insert img using longblob

```html
<?php
           if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
                {
                    echo "Please select an image.";
                }
                else
                {
                    $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                    $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                    $image= file_get_contents($image);
                    $image= base64_encode($image);
     $kod=$_POST['inputKodProduk'] ;
     $namaproduk= $_POST['inputNamaProduk'] ;     
     $spesifikasi=$_POST['inputSpesifikasi'] ;          
                    saveinfo($name,$image,$kod,$namaproduk,$spesifikasi);
                }
            }
            function saveinfo($name,$image,$kod,$namaproduk,$spesifikasi)
            {
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","Root","");
                mysql_select_db("test",$con);
                $qry="INSERT INTO `produk`(`product_code`, `product_name`, `product_desc`, `img_name`, `img`) VALUES ($kod,$namaproduk,$spesifikasi,$name,$image)";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                if($result)
                {
                    //echo "<br/>Simpan Data Berjaya.";
                }
                else
                {
                    //echo "<br/>Simpan Data Gagal";
                }
            }
            
        ?>
```

Comment: You've got a syntax issue in your query. Square brackets wouldn't work for text strings either. Ask `mysql_error()` just like in your last question. Also find a newer tutorial on PDO and prepared/bound values.

Comment: sorry, forgot to edit the code already realize the bracket and i already remove it still with the same problems.. Usually im using includes db.php to connect to php this is a test page to work the problems with longblob